# Is there a way to add a Guided Decision Table to a rule-flow-group in Decision Center (7.2)?

Tags: redhat-brms

I have ruleflow-groups set up in Decision Central as attribute options on my Guided Decision Rules. I would like to build a ruleflow-group for several Decision Tables. Is there a way to do this in 7.2?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by adding optional attributes in the guided rule editor by clicking on show options and adding a new attribute "ruleflow-group".

[screenshot of guided rule editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJouz.png)